# UVA 10023 SquareRoot Issue

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm stuck with [this](http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=964) problem of the UVA as I can't figure out why my solution is not good.

As long as I understand, the question is to get the integer square root of any given number from 1 to 10^1000. So my intention was to flip the bits of a BigInteger from position i/2, where i is the number of bits in the minimal two's-complement representation of the input and decrease the i value each time the square of my guess is still less than the input.

Notice that every input I've tried so far is getting the expected result!

The example for, lets say, sqrt(36) would be:

```
36 -> 100100
bitCount = 2 ( (6 - 1)/2 = 2)
guess = 100 (4)
(4 * 4 = 16 < 36) -> bitCount = 1;
guess = 110 (6)
(6 * 6 = 36 = 36) -> break;
```

So the solution to sqrt(36) is 6, awesome... This way the solution to sqrt(37), sqrt(38), sqrt(39), until sqrt(49) would be 6 too.

Maybe the code is more explanatory.

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = in.nextInt();
        BigInteger bi;
        for(int i = n; i != 0; i--){
            bi = new BigInteger(in.next());
            System.out.println(squareRoot(bi));
        }
        in.close();
    }

    private static BigInteger squareRoot(BigInteger N) {
        int bitCount = (N.bitLength() - 1)/2;
        int aux = 0;
        
        BigInteger guess = BigInteger.ZERO;
        
        while(bitCount >= 0){
            guess = guess.flipBit(bitCount);
            aux = guess.multiply(guess).compareTo(N);
            if(aux < 0)
                bitCount--;
            else if(aux != 0){
                guess = guess.flipBit(bitCount);
                bitCount--;
            }
            else{
                break;
            }
        }
        return guess;
    }
}
```

For sure it is not the best performance solution and it seems to be wrong, but could someone explain me the reason why it is wrong?

Thank you guys!

Comment: If you want to look at a `BigInteger` square root implementation that's gotten serious optimization work, you should check out [Guava's](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava/src/com/google/common/math/BigIntegerMath.java#207).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the problem statement:

> The Output
>
> For each test case, your program should print X in the same format as Y was given in input.
>
> Print a blank line between the outputs for two consecutive test cases.

I got an accepted submission by modifying your program to take this into account.

However, I would suggest binary search as a simpler approach (but the problem doesn't seem relly well defined since the number of test cases is not given, I think).

Comment: I forgot to thank you... Your answer really helped me! And just as a comment, evidently im not a algorithm genious, but i think that going from the most relevant bit to the less relevant gives a complexity of log2(n), is it? and Thankyou!

Comment: Yeah, I guess the two approches are quite equivalent.